# How can two exe running as different user can communicate using COM (Component Object Model)

Tags: c++, windows, com

I am new to COM. Can you please tell me how  can two exe running as different user (one as system other as either admin or non admin)can communicate using COM (Component Object Model)? If you have link of some demo code that will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [article](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/com/) is about the basics, but explains some fundamentals issues like the IPC you are asking for. The communication channel takes place thru a proxy automatically provided by the [Windows COM SCM](http://www.peterindia.net/COMOverview.html).

Comment: More about the impersonation and its impact on the proxy are available at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693709(v=vs.85).aspx